# React CreatableSelect on scroll event not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, pagination, react-select

I have fetched the option when the scroller is at middle. but its only triggering when the scroll bar at the bottom.

Here is the code I am trying to do:-
this is the function for scroll event:-

```
const onMenuScrollToBottom = (e: any) => {
    if (
      e.target.scrollTop + e.target.clientHeight >=
      e.target.scrollHeight * 0.5
    ) {
      if (total > options.length) {
        fetchOption();
        fetchOption({ pagination: true });
      }
    }
  };
```

Here is the code for react creatable component.

```
 <CreatableSelect
  onMenuScrollToBottom={onMenuScrollToBottom}
   />;
```